# jQuery isn't targetting the div i need it to

Tags: jquery, html

this is a simple one im sure but i cant think of how to get it to work. I've tried .next() and .nextAll() to no avail. The only thing i can think of is the functions i'm trying arent working due to the flow of the code. Anyway, below is the jquery and html for you. I'm just trying to make form-box fade in when download is clicked.

HTML:

```
                 <div class="pdfs">
                    <div class="pdf-left">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="images/pdfs/macrolux/1.jpg" width="100" height="79">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <div class="view">View</div>
                            <div class="download">Download</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pdf-right">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="images/pdfs/macrolux/2.jpg" width="100" height="79">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <div class="view">View</div>
                            <div class="download">Download</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-box">
                    Form
                </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.download').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('div.form-box').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: `div.download` doesn't have a `next` with the class `form-box`, does it? `next()` will *"Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements"*

Comment: Why are you using `on` and `next` in the first place? Are there multiple per page? Are they dynamically loaded elements?

Comment: i've tried it with putting .next('div.form-box') but it isn't doing it, nor is just .next(). I think it's because .form-box is a sibling of .pdfs and .download is quite deep into .pdfs - hence my issue

Comment: `.closest(".pdfs").next(".form-box")` will do the trick without parenting them manually.

Comment: Thank you! I've used what you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is fragile, if your document structure changes you need to rewrite the jquery.

A more generic solution is to give the form-box divs and your download divs related ids e.g.

```
<div id="download-1" class="download">
   Download<
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="download-1_formbox" class="form-box">
    Form
</div>`
```

Then in your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.download').on('click', function(){
        var divId=$(this).attr("id");
        $("#" + divId + "_formbox").fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Update: As per request, I've added a bit of code to make it toggle, working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HkeZ3/2/) / (only the 1st download link works,  didn't give the second one an id)

Comment: How can i make this toggle when download is clicked? Your solution works perfectly and i agree that this is more stable, however i'd like it to hide if i click download again. Also, if i click a seperate entity of .download how can i make the previous instance of it close?

Comment: fadein works by changing the css opacity property so something like (untested!) `var boxDiv = $("#" + divId + "_formbox"); if (boxDiv.css("opacity") == 0) { boxDiv.fadein('slow'); } else { boxdiv.fadeout('slow'); }`

Comment: oops I was slightly wrong, fadeIn and FadeOut also mess with display attribute. Here's a working fiddlee (only the first download link works, I didn't give an id to the second one) http://jsfiddle.net/HkeZ3/2/

Comment: This works well, i added a second to the jsFiddle to check it worked and it does. However what would you advise if the 1st form is opened, but the user clicks the second box? at the moment it displays both underneath each other which isn't the effect i'm after, ideally i'd like all others to close when another is clicked. Thanks for all your help by the way!

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/HkeZ3/4/ - I'm not sure if or how you can make teh animations run in parallel, but it fades out all the other form-box divs. I messed up your structure but the principle will work no matter how you structure your divs.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! I switched the structure back just to double check and it's working exactly how it should. Really appreciate all the help, fantastic knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `$(this).next()`, you can test it in chrome/firefox:

```
console.log($('div.download').next());
```

to get the right `div`, try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.download').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kLGWv/1/)**

or if there is only one `form-box` you wish to hide:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.download').on('click', function(){
      $('div.form-box').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Should have known about the .parent() function. Thanks v much!

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/DELwR/) should be enough if you are not having more than one `div.form-box`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.download').on('click', function(){
      $('div.form-box').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

And if  you have `div.form-box` after each `pdfs`  `div` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.download').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parents('.pdfs').next('div.form-box').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DELwR/1/)**

Comment: I will be having more than one which is why i was trying to do the $(this).next() method, its a pain

Comment: do you have `div.form-box` after each  `pdfs` div ??

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).next()` will target any next sibling node, not "everything what comes after this in the HTML".

You can do the following:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().next().fadeIn('slow');
```

Take not this is not recommended: Each change you make to your DOM, will make your JS change. You can better target the `.form-box` itself.